# Cant sort words in ascending order by using sort method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I think the problem is that javascript doesn't recognise that input field must be taken as an array

Where is the problem?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  

  <script>
  
  function myFunction(){
  var longWords = new Array (document.getElementById("text").value);
  longWords.sort(function (a, b) {
  return b.length - a.length;
  })
  document.writeln(longWords);
  } 
  </script>

 </head>

 <body>
 <h1>Enter sentence in field</h1>
  <input id = "text" type = "text"/>
  <button onclick = "myFunction()">Sort text</button>
  
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You **cannot** initialize an array from a string.

Comment: @hindmost yes you can. It's the same as doing `var longWords = ["someString"]`

Comment: @Thomas Obviously I meant initialization in the way the OP wanted

Comment: @hindmost how would you write it so that it worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  

  <script>
  
  function myFunction(){
  var longWords = document.getElementById("text").value.split(' ');
  longWords.sort();
  document.writeln(longWords);
  } 
  </script>

 </head>

 <body>
 <h1>Enter sentence in field</h1>
  <input id = "text" type = "text"/>
  <button onclick = "myFunction()">Sort text</button>
  
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: interesting, the answer is basically the same as mine, and later written, but lacks any explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) for spliting the string by space, then you get an array with words.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var longWords = document.getElementById("text").value.split(' ');
    longWords.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.length - a.length;
    });
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(longWords));
}
```

```html
<h1>Enter sentence in field</h1>
<input id = "text" type = "text"/>
<button onclick = "myFunction()">Sort text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you looking to sort a string and convert to array , have a look on below code snippet

```js
var arr =[];
function convertToArray(text) {
  arr.push(text.split(''));
  console.log(arr);
}



function sortAlphabets(text) {
    console.log(text.split('').sort().join(''));
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name">
<button onclick="sortAlphabets(document.getElementById('name').value);convertToArray(document.getElementById('name').value);">click</button>
```